# Not selecting data from table

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to use Python to manually update a SQLite database created in django.

I found the name of the DB and am testing using a `select` but I am getting an error that I do not understand.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("SELECT * from oncall_pduser")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fcb92697650>
>>> conn.execute("SELECT * from oncall_pduser")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fcb92697880>
```

**Question**

What does this error mean?

These are the parms and I am running Python logged in as root

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root 38912 May  9 16:47 db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fcb92697650>` is not an error - it is a `Cursor` object *string representation*. To see the actual results of the query, use [`fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) method:

```
c.execute("SELECT * from oncall_pduser")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Or, to be more memory efficient, you can just iterate over the cursor:

```
for row in c:
    print(row)
```

Comment: `for row in c:` would be more efficient.